# Automatically reorder factor levels in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have many factor columns, spread randomly throughout a data.frame.  These factor columns have 6 levels ranging from `"Very Strongly Disagree"` to `"Very Strongly Agree"`

I am looking for a way to automatically re-level every factor variable that has these levels into a pre-specified order.  I am currently doing this manually for some 30 columns like so:

```
data$immigration <- factor(data$immigration,  
    levels = c("Very Strongly Disagree", "Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Moderately
    Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Very Strongly Agree"))
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this in a dplyr chain that automatically relevels ALL the factors which contain the above levels (or really just one of the above levels?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

l <- c("Very Strongly Disagree", "Strongly Disagree", "Disagree",
       "Moderately Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Very Strongly Agree")

set.seed(1)
df <- 
  tibble(
    A = factor(sample(l, 10, TRUE)),
    B = factor(sample(l, 10, TRUE)),
    N = 1:10,
    S = letters[1:10],
    Z = factor(letters[1:10])
  )
levels(df$A)
#> [1] "Disagree"               "Moderately Agree"      
#> [3] "Strongly Agree"         "Strongly Disagree"     
#> [5] "Very Strongly Agree"    "Very Strongly Disagree"
levels(df$B)
#> [1] "Strongly Agree"         "Strongly Disagree"     
#> [3] "Very Strongly Agree"    "Very Strongly Disagree"


df2 <-
  df %>% 
  mutate_if(~is.factor(.) & all(levels(.) %in% l), factor, levels = l)

levels(df2$A)
#> [1] "Very Strongly Disagree" "Strongly Disagree"     
#> [3] "Disagree"               "Moderately Agree"      
#> [5] "Strongly Agree"         "Very Strongly Agree"
levels(df2$B)
#> [1] "Very Strongly Disagree" "Strongly Disagree"     
#> [3] "Disagree"               "Moderately Agree"      
#> [5] "Strongly Agree"         "Very Strongly Agree"
```

Here `mutate_if` is used with the condition `~is.factor(.) & all(levels(.) %in% l)` which means that we apply releveling only to factor columns where all the levels lie in our pre-specified vector of levels.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `is.factor`, but the rest of this is a good solution.

Comment: @bouncyball I think it's so they can apply the function in `mutate_if` to all columns that are 1) factors and 2) contain the factor levels of interest. This way, they don't have to know which columns fit that description, which should help the solution scale

Comment: @bouncyball technically you can create something which is not a factor, but has levels. E.g. `x <- 1:3;levels(x) <- "z"`

Comment: This is a really nice solution with automatic level detection, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this warrants a new question, but I now have the issue of needing to automatically detect all factors with levels `Yes` and `No`, and recode those levels as `1` and `0`.  I'm trying to use a combination of `mutate_if` and `recode`, but to no avail.  My attempt   ```mutate_if(~is.factor(.) & all(levels(.) %in% yes_no, recode_factor(., !!!yes_no_key))) ``` where ```yes_no = c("Yes", "No")``` and
```yes_no_key <- c(Yes = 1, No = 2)```  Thoughts?

Comment: @Parseltongue do you want to recode it to a factor with levels "0" and "1" or to an integer with values 0 and 1?

Comment: Nevermind!  I figured it out ```mutate_if(~is.factor(.) & all(levels(.) %in% yes_no), funs(recode_factor(., "Yes" = 1, "No" = 0)```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [`mutate_at`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html) function, along with a defined function to accomplish this (you don't *have* to define the function, it just makes the code a little cleaner IMO). Here, we define the column names ahead of time. If you are trying to edit all of the character columns in your data, you could use `mutate_if(is.character, create_factor)`

```
create_factor <- function(x, 
                          levels = c("Very Strongly Disagree",
                          "Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Moderately
                          Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Very Strongly Agree")){

  factor(x, levels)
} 

column_names <- c("immigration")

data %>%
  mutate_at(column_names, create_factor)
```

Comment: This is a very neat way to do this.  Is there a way to automatically detect all the columns that have those factors, rather than pre-specifying?